# Submitting an Unordered List in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC, but i have noticed that there is no helper for an unordered list. what i want to do is when a user clicks on a checkbox it will add items to a list, however i am struggling to add to this to my model on submission

This is the HTML

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="attachmentPanel">

                <ul id="contractors"></ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is the javascript, which fires when the checkbox is clicked

```
function SelectedUser(name) {

    var ul = document.getElementById("contractors");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

basically when the user clicks on submit i want the items in the UL list to be submitted to my controller

Comment: is your view bind with any model?

Comment: yes this is represented in my model

Answer (score 0):

if your list contain only string than you can create a function to get the values from the list

```
<script>


function getvalues(){
  var mylist = []
   var elem = document.getElementById("contractors")
   for(let f of elem.children){
     mylist.push(f.innerText);
   }
  return mylist;
}
function submit(){
   var list = getvalues();
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: @Url.Action("submitItems", "Demo")',
      data: JSON.stringify(list),
       dataType: 'application/json',
        success : function(response){
                alert(response);
        }
     });
}
</script>

<button onclick="submit()" >submit</button>
```

Now on your controller

```
namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    public class DemoController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public string submitItems(string[] items)
        {

            return "success";
        }
    }
}
```